# redirect to different link based on item pattern inside angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a angularjs ng-repeat code block like this:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="i in clinvar | filter: query | orderBy: order: direction | limitTo: totalDisplayed">
 <td data-title="CR ID"><a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/variation/{{ i.c2 }}" target="_blank">{{ i.c2 }}</a></td>
</tr>
```

`i.c2` is an ID, by clicking the ID, it can link to other website, the real project is here:
[ID Demo](http://3dgb.cbi.pku.edu.cn/disease/)

The problem is the ID come from two database and need redirect to different link based on its pattern. The pattern is based on if it contains a period, the logic is like this:
[Logic Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUnkb.png)

I am pretty new to angularjs, hope you can help me how to solve the problem. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should do the trick:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="i in clinvar | filter: query | orderBy: order: direction | limitTo: totalDisplayed">
  <td data-title="CR ID">
    <a href="{{(i.c2.indexOf('.') > -1) ? 'http://website2.com' : 'http://website1.com' }}/{{ i.c2 }}" target="_blank">{{ i.c2 }}</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/ys6DLt/